# How is it that CLT can be used for around 8 light bulbs?

Tags: self-study, central-limit-theorem

I have been given the following problem.

The light bulbs available have an average lifetime of 1000 hours with a standard deviation of 50 hours. How many light bulbs should we stock so that we can be sure to keep the light on for at least 7200 hours with a probability of at least 98% ?

The answer is given as
[image: answer]

How is it OK to invoke CLT here? I thought we needed a sample of over 30 or a normal distribution.

Comment: It depends on the distribution you start with and how far into the tail you look (and your tolerance for approximation). If my original variable's distribution was say a beta(7,5) then 8 observations would in many cases be plenty to use a normal approximation for the sum or the average. On the other hand if it was a lognormal with $\sigma$ parameter 4 then a sample size of thousands or even millions would not suffice, for all that  the actual CLT (which makes no mention of any finite sample size) still applies. Light globe lives tend to be fairly right skew and I wouldn't be confident at n= 8

Comment: @Glen_b Agreed, but notice the statistics given imply a CV of 50/1000 = 0.05, which means a lognormal $\sigma$ around $0.05$ is more plausible -- and such distributions aren't very skew. Thus, although the Normal approximation could be poor, the answer *relative to the expected value* is not going to be too far off.

Comment: I'd try to avoid examining the data I want to test in order to decide what to assume about the populations -- especially when it's so small I can't feasibly pull out some of it at random to look at and test the rest. Usually - and especially in the case of small samples - I'd rely on what's understood about the variable. I agree -- when we examine it, it's clear enough that a t-test would be fine -- but I would try to avoid examining it since I no longer have a basis for claiming my overall testing process with that data-dependent step will remain very close to the desired $α$.   ... ctd

Comment: ctd ... even more concerning would be the impact of doing it for each assumption.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you don't need exactly N=30 for the normal approximation to be somewhat good. It can be more, or less, good depending how skewed or platy- or lepto-kurtic the data are. However, I think it's valid to claim that we don't have specifics about how good "somewhat good" would be for an approximation in this case. Alas this seems to be one of the homework questions where you're just supposed to use the methods you know, and not read ahead too much, and because there's no other answer with the limited premise.

Comment: Thank you. That is just how I feel about it! Especially as the answer claims that we don't know the distribution.